# Scytale cipher plaintext and Z implementation

Tags: java

I'm having this trouble in Scytale cipher when displaying the plaintext, and also the "z" letter if there is lacking in the rows and columns.

To make the explanation easier, I want the plaintext to be displayed like this:

---

### H E L L O

### W O R L D

### Z Z Z Z Z

---

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class scytale{

    public static String scytaleEncode(String plaintext, int numRows){
        String encodedText = "";
        if(numRows>=plaintext.length() || numRows <=0){
            System.out.println(plaintext + "z");
        }
        else{
            while(plaintext.length()%numRows != 0){
                plaintext += " ";
            }
            int numCols = plaintext.length()/numRows;
            for(int i = 0; i<numCols; i++){
                for (int y = i; y <plaintext.length(); y+=numCols;){
                    encodedText += plaintext.charAt(y);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        return encodedText;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("-------WELCOME TO SCYTALE CIPHER-------");
        String cont;
        do{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("=================================");
            System.out.println("Enter the String for Encryption: ");
            String message = new String();
            message = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\nEnter your key: ");
            int key;
            key = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\nCiphered:" + scytaleEncode(message.replaceAll("\\s",""), key));
            System.out.println("\nWould you like to continue? (y/n): ");
            cont = sc.next();
            System.out.println("\n");
        }while(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

        System.out.println("Thank you for using SCYTALE CIPHER!\n");
    }
}
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
package cryptool;

import java.util.*;

public class scytale {

    public static String scytaleEncode(String plaintext, int numRows) {
        String encodedText = "";
        if (numRows >= plaintext.length() || numRows <= 0) {
            System.out.println(plaintext + "z");
        } else {
            while (plaintext.length() % numRows != 0) {
                plaintext += " ";
            }
            int numCols = plaintext.length() / numRows;
            for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
                for (int y = i; y < plaintext.length(); y += numCols) {
                    encodedText += plaintext.charAt(y);
                    System.out.println(encodedText);
                    System.out.println(plaintext);
                }
            }
            return encodedText;
        }
        return encodedText;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-------WELCOME TO SCYTALE CIPHER-------");
        String cont;
        do {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("=================================");
            System.out.println("Enter the String for Encryption: ");
            // String message = new String();
            String message = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\nEnter your key: ");
            int key;
            key = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\nCiphered:" + scytaleEncode(message.replaceAll("\\s", ""), key));
            System.out.println("\nWould you like to continue? (y/n): ");
            cont = sc.next();
            System.out.println("\n");
        } while (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

        System.out.println("Thank you for using SCYTALE CIPHER!\n");
    }
}
```